# Binding ng-model inside ng-repeat loop in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to deal with the issue of scope inside of an ng-repeat loop - I've browsed quite a few questions but have not quite been able to get my code to work.

Controller code:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.lines = [{text: 'res1'}, {text:'res2'}];
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-app>
     <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
       <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
           <div class="preview">{{text}}{{$index}}</div>

       </div>
       <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
           <-- typing here should auto update it's preview above -->
           <input value="{{line.text}}" ng-model="text{{$index}}"/>
            <!-- many other fields here that will also affect the preview -->
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/zqTah/

Basically I have an object (it's a flyer generator) which contains multiple lines of text. Each line of text can be tweaked by the user (text, font, size, color, etc) and I want to create a preview for it. The example above only shows the input field to enter text and I would like that to automatically/as-you-type update the preview div but there will be many more controls.

I am also not sure I got the code right for the looping index - is that the best way to create a ng-model name inside the loop?

Comment: the fiddle doesn't seem to work ..

Answer (score 116, accepted):

For each iteration of the ng-repeat loop, `line` is a reference to an object in your array.  Therefore, to preview the value, use `{{line.text}}`.

Similarly, to databind to the text, databind to the same: `ng-model="line.text"`.  You don't need to use `value` when using ng-model (actually you shouldn't).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/7MhLd/).

For a more in-depth look at scopes and ng-repeat, see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs), section **ng-repeat**.

Comment: what about the e2e test of this code? I mean how to select an input if it model is dynamic?

Comment: Do the items being iterated have to be objects then?  In other words they can't be primitives, like strings, e.g. $scope.lines = ['a', 'b', 'c'] ?

Comment: @berto, yes, they must be objects.  This is discussed in the linked reference, "What are the nuances of scope prototypal...".

Comment: I've got a similar ng-repeat/ng-model issue.  I've done some research and I think I'm almost there. If anyone could take a look I'd really appreciate it.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855575/angular-further-dynamic-filtering-issue

Answer (score 2):

```
<h4>Order List</h4>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="val in filter_option.order">
        <span>
            <input title="{{filter_option.order_name[$index]}}" type="radio" ng-model="filter_param.order_option" ng-value="'{{val}}'" />
            &nbsp;{{filter_option.order_name[$index]}}
        </span>
        <select title="" ng-model="filter_param[val]">
            <option value="asc">Asc</option>
            <option value="desc">Desc</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```