# How to track multiple radio buttons and checkboxes created in a table using ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I am new to AngularJS. I would like to know how to track which all radio buttons and checkboxes were clicked or selected on clicking the submit button. The tables rows were created using ng-repeat. The checkboxes(as seen in the image) appear when the radio button in the third column is clicked(I do an ng-show="true") and can be selected.

Attached is a mockup.

[image]

Any good design pattern or sample code as well for this use case?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding sample code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in data">
    <td><input type="radio" name={{event.performanceID}}
        ng-value="yes" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name={{event.performanceID}} ng-value="no" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name={{event.performanceID}}
        ng-value="maybe" />
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label> <input type="checkbox"> Approve
            </label> <label> <input type="checkbox"> Bonuses
            </label>
        </div></td>
    <td><img
        ng-src="http://google.com/images/{{ event.imageName }}.jpg"
        style="height: 100px; width: 100px" /></td>
    <td>
        <div>
            <h4>Persons Name</h4>
            <h5>{{event.Ename}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Address</h4>
            <h5>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h5>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show at least some code of what you attempted to do

Comment: I added the code, Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as i understand you need to know what are the selected events per person, is that right?

Comment: Would you please make a fiddle, or a plunkr of what you have?

Comment: Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/14410993/3809894