# summation of reactive angular values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that holds x number stocks in a JSON format and I am having a user enter the amount of shares they hold for each stock. My application will display the user's held value (`valuePerShare * shares`) for each stock.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in stocks">
        {{ x.symbol + ', ' + x.valuePerShare }}
        <p>Enter number of shares owned : <input type="text" ng-model="shares"></p>
        <p ng-if='shares'>{{shares}} shares. Value total: {{(x.valuePerShare*shares)}} </p>
    </li>
    <li> Summary: </li>
    <li> {{ stocks.length + ' stocks in portfolio' }} </li>
</ul>
```

How can I give a "portfolio total" in the summary that sums up `x.valuePerShare*shares` for all x stocks? Is there someway to grab that reactive value outside of the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I really think that should be a `total()` method on your controller, and not something you should do in your template.

Comment: @Pevara how can i grab the user inputs from the controller? sorry if this is a dumb question. brand new to angular

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410993/binding-ng-model-inside-ng-repeat-loop-in-angularjs