# concatenate an ng repeat item as an object inside ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to concatenate an `ng-repeat` item to ng-model object.  I was wondering if this possible.

so for example:

```
//array
$scope.array = [
 {
   param: 'color',
   ....
 },
 {
   param: 'weight',
   .....
 }
]
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
  {{ item.param }}

   <input type="text" ng-model="form.name.{{ item.param }}" >
</div>
```

so lets say `{{ item.param }}` is `color`, the `ng-model` will be `form.name.color`.

form object will be something like this:

```
{

  name: {
   color: 'value of input',
   weight: 'value of input'
  }

}
```

How can I concatenate the item.param to the object form.name?  I've been trying so many ways but no results.  I trying to use `$index`, but don't know where to begin.

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410993/binding-ng-model-inside-ng-repeat-loop-in-angularjs

Comment: @fubbe This could be a duplicate if I didn't have `form.name` in the `ng-model`, in that case it'll just be `ng-model = "item.param"`.  I need `form` object, because I'm sending this as new object, and would like to have the `item.param` as a key in the `form.name` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/8mtr7513/1/) fiddle.

Your `ng-model` should look like this:

```
ng-model="form.name[item.param]"
```