# How to get value of an input field with same id in Angular4

Tags: angularjs, angular

This is my form

```
<button (click)="M_add()">Add</button>
<tbody id="_tbody">
</tbody>
```

When the add button is clicked, it will create an input field

```
var tbody = document.getElementById("_tbody");
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var col = document.createElement("td");
var col_index = document.createElement("input");
col_index.setAttribute("class", "index");
col_index.setAttribute("id", "index");
row.appendChild(col_index);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

I need to retrieve value from each input field, how to get it?

Comment: You can only have 1 id per page. Append a number to your id instead like `'index_' + ctr`.

Comment: how to add that one ? and how to retrieve their value?

Comment: I posted an answer but it's not  using the approach above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by angular text() function

```
$('#id').text()
```

Comment: by using this i only get first value

Comment: you can use $scope to store count variable.
$scope.count = 0;
in M_add function, increase this by 1.
$scope.count++; 
then add it in id of element
col_index.setAttribute("id", "index_"+$scope.count+"");

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer in `AngularJS` but I think the concept is still there.

```
$scope.table = [
  { value: 1 },
  { value: 2}
];
$scope.getRowValue = (row) => {
  $scope.selectedRow = row;
};
$scope.addTableRow = () => {
  $scope.table.push({
    value: $scope.table.length + 1
  });
};
```

This approach uses an array of the things that you want to display in the table. Every time you add a new row, it is appended to the array.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in table">
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="{{row.value}}" ng-model="row.model" ng-init="row.model=row.value">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="getRowValue(row.model)">Get Row Value</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button ng-click="addTableRow()">Add Table Row</button>
```

In the HTML, the array is displayed in `ng-repeat`. Each instance of `ng-model` is a reference to an object in the array. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411131/4110257)

So basically what happens when user clicks on the button it will get the `model` of the input in that row and pass it to somewhere.

Check the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlinph/o4ch9er2/)